# Return every item in a list from a foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

```
List<object> li = new List <object>(Items);
string name = "";
foreach (var item in Items)
{
    name = item["title"].ToString();
}
return name;
```

Using this code snippet, I can't find a way for to change the return to output *all* items from the list. As is, it only returns the last item. How can I get every item returned?

Comment: make a new list and return it..

Comment: It would help to see where this method is consumed

Comment: How do you want them returned? Do you want them somehow made into a single string? do you want to return a list of strings or something else...

Comment: Do what @Sayse says, or explain more specifically what shape you expect the combined set of items to be in.

Comment: What type of object is Items?

Comment: -1 more information needed. Though it seems like you are on a wild track

Comment: Also, as no-one has stated it yet: Your first line of code is probably obsolete, as you do not use your `li` variable (and the newly created `List` instance it points to) anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

You have to return a new list, in your example you're just setting name to the current name then returning name at the end. Since you loop through all the elements name is set to the final value in the list before returning. Besides that, your return type is `string` unless you concatinate all the elements in `li` into a single string then you can't return a list as a string.

```
 List<string> newList = li.Select(x => x["title"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Will create a new list of strings where each element is the title of an element from your source list, `li`.

If you really want to return a string you can use (I believe) `String.Join` or, (this one I'm certain of) `Aggregate` like so;

```
 return li.Aggregate((c, n) => c["title"].ToString() + ", " + b["title"].ToString());
```

The above code will return string that is a comma separated list of the elements titles.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little rediculous for just returning a list but it works. I would personally just return the whole thing at once.

```
    List<object> li = new List <object>(Items);
    string name = "";
    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        yield return item["title"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `yield return` and `return`within one method? If I remember correctly, this will not compile.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it thanks I was thinking that it would complain about not all paths exicuting a return

Comment: Your code will not compile. Assignment cannot happen in the `yield return`

Comment: Also if this is not your recommended solution why not include the recommended solution that returns the whole thing at once?

Comment: @Chris because he didn't ask for my opinion he asked how to return one thing at a time

Comment: He wanted to return each item in the list. You're basically returning an ienumerable at the moment. If you think returning a list is better (for example) then that still qualifies as returning each item in the list...

Comment: Given that the OP did not seem to expect to only get back the last item based on his or her code, I fear he or she may not understand concepts such as the `yield return`-compiler magic iterators created by the C# compiler and how to use them without any further explanations yet. BTW, what purpose does the `name` variable serve in your code?

Comment: lol To everyone that has a problem with this answer... As I understood the question, the OP wanted to do a return of each item from a foreach loop. I answered that question. Its not a big deal, relax lol...

Answer (score 0):

As you know, method can returns one value **with return statement**. So you shoud to return all items as IEnumerable (List, Array, etc).

```
 return Items.Select(x => x["Title"].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the whole List and extract each element when you want to use them. You *cannot* pass all these elements at once unless you store them in some sort of container (an array, for example.)

Again, this does not make much sense if you already have a List object to house them. The CLR's `List<T>` type is an adjustable length array, not the classic linked list.

If you can post more detail as to what your exact scenario is, we can help you better.